# Can't access X-Total-Count header from json-server

Tags: axios, json-server

I am requesting data from JSON server using axios. While I can see that JSON server is returning the `X-Total-Count` header using Postman, but axios does not see that header. I am using http protocol, so CORS should not be an issue. What am I missing?

Here's the call to json-server:

```
const resp = await axios.get('/orders?_start=0&_end=100');
const orderCount = resp.headers['X-Total-Count'];
```

Here are the headers received (captured in Chrome Devtools). Note that `X-Total-Count` is missing:

[image]

The same HTTP call in Postman shows that `X-Total-Count` is returned:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I used the command line option `--no-cors` and axios started seeing the X-Total-Count header.